# How do I make this url redirection work in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

need help on setting up redirects if the url has /pages/ in it and is browse using mobile they will be redirected to the following path like this.

google.com/pages/tutorial
TO
google.com/a/b/pages/tutorial

Here's my code below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if (screen.width <= 699 && url = "pages") {
document.location.href = ''+'/a/s'+ window.location.pathname;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Your condition looks weird, isn't `url.includes('pages')` ?

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this achieve your goal?

```js
if (document.location.href.includes("pages"))
  document.location.href = document.location.href.replace("pages", "a/b/pages");
```

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on [@async awiat's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70253603/17344437), the following will also check the screen width.

```
if (screen.width <= 699 && document.location.href.includes("pages")) {
    document.location = "name-of-path"; 
}
```